# NSArray Thread 1 error on scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a `NSArray` to store the names of pictures that I want to use in a `UITableViewCell`. When I pull the table view too much to scroll the app crashes and gives me:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xc).

This is what I'm using to initialize my Array:

In my .h:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *imagesToDisplay;
```

In my .m:
(`viewDidLoad`)

```
_imagesToDisplay = @[@[@"one.png", @"two.png", @"three.png"],
                        @[@"four.png", @"five.png", @"six.png"],
                        @[@"seven.png", @"eight.png", @"nine.png"],
                        @[@"ten.png", @"eleven.png", @"twelve.png"],
                        @[@"thirteen.png", @"fourteen.png", @"fifteen.png"],
                        @[@"sixthteen.png", @"seventeen.png", @"eighteen.png"]
                        ];
```

This is what I'm doing to retrieve the image and set the image view as those images:

```
int row = [indexPath row];
cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imagesToDisplay[row][0]];
cell.image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imagesToDisplay[row][1]];
cell.image3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imagesToDisplay[row][2]];
```

Even when I comment out the different cell.image lines they still give me the thread 1 error. My specific error is

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xc).

I'm new to objective c so anything helps. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using automatic reference counting (ARC)? If so, your `retain` should be `strong`, or you can omit it entirely as that is the default now in Xcode 5.

Comment: That's not going to cause the crash. Can you upload the full stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @SiLo: With ARC, "retain" and "strong" are synonyms, there is no difference.

Comment: @MartinR Learn something new every day! I thought they had subtle differences, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is merely an exercise in multi-dimensional arrays but I would recommend against this.

Your first step should be to create a proper data model (class object) for your table. For example:

```
@interface ImageRow : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *imagePaths;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array;

- (NSString)imagePathAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

Then you would store an `NSArray` of `ImageRows` instead of the multi-dimensional array. Fundamentally, you are accomplishing the same thing but it's both more clear and more extensible.

Your crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is typically when you try to access an object that is `nil` when you're expecting it not to be. In most cases, Obj-C will handle it gracefully but there are times where it does not.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is because you are not retaining an autoreleased object. When you say a property is `retain`, the memory management is only done for you if you use its setter, typically by using `self.property =`. You are instead accessing the backing ivar directly. Because array literals are autoreleased and you have failed to retain it, the array is autoreleased and `_imagesToDisplay` points to garbage. Add a retain call or use its setter to fix this.

Also SiLo is right about the data model.

Comment: I'm new to objective c but that makes sense. Would I add a like like [_imagesToDisplay retain] somewhere

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean by "add a retain call." It should be in the viewDidLoad, not "somewhere". you can also change `_imagesToDisplay = ` to `self.imagesToDisplay`.